# Would it be possible to iterate over typescript files in a folder and start a worker thread for each using `ts-node`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node, worker-thread

## Overview

How would one start a worker thread with `ts-node`? Every attempt that I've made leads to a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error.

## Various Attempts

Currently, I'm attempting to spawn a new worker thread using this syntax:

```js
new Worker("fileToRunAsWorkerThread.ts");
```

That results in a `ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION: Unknown file extension ".ts"` error. I have also tried:

- Passing no file extension (`fileToRunAsWorkerThread`) (`MODULE_NOT_FOUND`)
- Passing the file with a Javascript file extension a Javascript extension  (`fileToRunAsWorkerThread.js`), both resulting in the same `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error (the actual file is still `.ts`).

I also tried passing different environment variables, as shown in the `ts-node` documentation https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/recipes/other/, all of which returned the same `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error, in combination with all of the different file extension combinations shown above.

## Environment configuration:

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ESnext",
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "outDir": "target",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "files": true,
        "swc": true,
        "esm": true
    }
}
```

Relevant sections of `package.json`:

```json
    "main": "./core/main.ts",
    "type": "module",
```

Node version:       v17.3.0

TS-node version:    v10.9.1

Typescript version: v5.0.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated, let me know if there's any ways I could improve my question!

## EDIT

I gave up and switched to TSC.

Comment: My guess is you can't do this with ts-node alone.  You need the compiled JS file to pass to the Worker, since you can't run a TS file directly..